# Is there anything wrong with using a PC power cord for a miter saw?

Tags: electrical, powertools

I just bought a used miter saw that needs a new power cord.  I found this [one](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/power-cord-gauge-2wire-p-66447.html) but $25 for a cord seems a bit steep.  That "official" cord is 16AWG with two wires.  I also found [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=5286) when I searched for 16AWG power cord.  Is there a reason I couldn't just cut the PC connector side off and wire it up to the saw?

Comment: Not going to tell you its right or wrong, but I've used one as a replacement for a circular saw power cord.

Comment: I buy replacement cordage from McMaster-Carr for more like $4 for 16ga and $7 for 12ga.  It's a common enough item that you don't need to buy it from some random website and have to set up an account and get rooked on shipping. Amazon prime probably has it too. if there's any dimension that matters, it's the outside diameter of the cable.

Comment: PC power cords tend to be a bit stiffer than the rubber jacketed power tool cords (they typically use a vinyl jacket).  I'd have to agree with @Harper that searching around on the after-market for a better price is going to be your best bet.

Comment: @Harper Well I just ordered one from McMaster and only *after* the order was done did I get a message saying that applicable shipping charges will be added and even now with the order complete I still don't know what those charges are.

Comment: @Harper I just reread your post about getting rooked by shipping charges and then face palmed.  I had a hard time finding the right thing on Amazon because the popularity of PC power cords dwarfs that of power tool power cords.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't mean to suggest McMaster was free shipping. They are sane though, they don't profiteer and they ship short distances because they have distribution centers within a day of most addresses.

Comment: @Harper I didn't think it was free shipping but I thought it would tell me what the shipping would be before the order was complete.  It's ok though I replied to their email confirmation that if shipping is more than $1.00 to cancel my order and they did saying that shipping would have been $6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't splice it, but install it by hooking it up internally consistent with the way the original one was (including noting the conductor type, aluminum vs copper), then you will be fine.